# linuxdeployqt argument list too long

Tags: linux, qt

I am making a bash file in order to resolve all my qt app dependencies without having to do it manually. This is my code within the message it is giving me an error on the linuxdeployqt level which is: "../build-app-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_GCC_64bit-Release/app: Argument list too long"
which is not the case when I run it manually. Can anyone help me resolving this issue please?

[image]

Comment: You have a typo in `path_delpoy`

Comment: I corrected it but still...

Comment: You also have a space in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` after `$path_deploy`. Try changing the space to a colon `:`

Comment: it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I found where's the error come from and it's from the export PATH... where it only takes a full path. I don't know why it can't be otherwise, if anybody have an answer to this I'd be glad to hear it